# Runtime 91 when running from saved workbook

Tags: vba, excel

first time post here cause for the first time I couldn't find an answer on Stack.

The program I'm fiddling with goes to an API website - gets the passport key - and uses that to load the info in XML and then parses it. The code is very long so I'm only posting the bit that results in the error.

```
myURL = "https://api.smartbidnet.com/project?PassportKey=" & PassportKey & "&ResultType=xml"  'This is the API URL where we use our passport key to get our data
IE.Navigate myURL 'Go to Webpage
Dim XDoc As Object   
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & myURL)  'Here we will load the XML info     from the web page
Set lists = XDoc.DocumentElement  'lists will be used to access XML nodes
Set Projects = lists.SelectNodes("//root/projects")
```

Now heres the weird part:

If I open excel by selecting "Blank Workbook" the code works just fine from the editor.

If I save the blank workbook and then try to run it or If I simply right click the desktop and open a blank sheet rather than workbook and try to run it. the last line results in

> Runtime 91 error

Any help is of course greatly appreciated.

The bit of code before the above is simply navigating to the site to grab the passport key for the API and build the myURL variable.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? And in your thorough research about that particular error you couldn't find anything about an object reference being `Nothing`? Protip: to make a good answerable question, the trick isn't to post "the bit that results in the error" pulled out of context; the trick is to put up a self-contained [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I could be wrong but I suspect removing this `ThisWorkbook.Path &` in the 2nd to last line will solve the issue.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman TBH I've no idea what `XDoc.Load ("C:\SomePathhttps://api.smartbidnet.com/project?PassportKey=1234567890&ResultType=xml")` is supposed to be doing. Definitely doesn't look legit though. IOW yeah, it only "works just fine" when `ThisWorkbook.Path` yields an empty string / the workbook isn't saved.

Comment: Look into how breakpoints (F9), step-through (F8), step-over (Shift+F8), the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and *locals* toolwindow can do for you.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - yes. That statement about working when opening a blank workbook tipped me off to that bad syntax. Maybe you know this the load method expects a source for the XML (I have typically used direct file paths with this method.) TBH, I am skeptical that it will load directly from an API call (but I don't have the experience to comment to much on that). I've really only used `httprequest` for webservices.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - your answer was correct. Bad syntax on my part - its something I copied and pasted from another post. And also, yes - it loads the API call!

Comment: @Mat'sMug - sorry, I meant to state the last line produced the error. Thanks for the insight though. I wanted to post the code buuuuut its about 3000 lines long so may have been counter productive.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I warmly recommend you read up about how to write a [mcve] for your next questions.